# SSRS deselecting from Multi Value Parameter issue

Tags: reporting-services

I am having issues with Multi Value Parameter in SSRS Report.

My Parameter contains 10 values. If I Deselect All the values from Parameter I get error that the Parameter cannot be blank so I go back to the drop down and it does not get filled in with the values. I deleted two items from the Parameter and I do not get issues and my list gets populated if I deselect everything.

Comment: Your question is a wee bit hard to follow. It would help if you'd provide an [reproducible scenario](http://sscce.org) and tell us what you've done/tried so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong, You are saying your parameter drop down gets cleared out once you get the error that "Parameters cannot be blank" ? How about checking "Allow blank" in parameter properties http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337234(v=SQL.100).aspx ?

Another thing you may like to check is, if there is any non-ascii character in your parameter drop down's available value. Manipulating this parameter values at run time (check/uncheck) could eventually lead to unexpected behaviors like parameters clearing out or report never rendering.